# Could not get to a route in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-routing

Why can't I get to the controller in my asp.net core application. Please see code below.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using HashingApplication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using NgWithJwt.Models;

namespace NgWithJwt.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class UserController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext context;

        public UserController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [Route("add-user")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddUser(AppUser model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var saltValue = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + model.Password;
                var password = Encryption.Encrypt(model.Password, saltValue);

                model.SaltValue = saltValue;
                model.Password = password;
                model.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;

                context.Add(model);
                var response = await context.SaveChangesAsync();
                if(response > 0)
                {
                    return Ok(model);
                }
            }
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my class for model

```
 public partial class AppUser
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Username is required.")]
        [DisplayName("Username")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is required")]
        [DisplayName("First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
        [DisplayName("Middle Name")]
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last Name is required")]
        [DisplayName("Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(max)")]
        public string SaltValue { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
        [DisplayName("Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
        public string UserType { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    }
```

My server is running so I try accessing it with postman like so:

```
{
    "Username": "juan",
    "FirstName": "Juan",
    "MiddleName": "A.",
    "LastName": "Dela Cruz",
    "Password": "password",
    "UserType": "User"
}
```

Server is running at

> "https://localhost:44366/"

I use this url to post data

> http://localhost:44366/api/user/add-user

This is the error I get on postman. I am using the debug mode to get to my controller break point.

[image]

Comment: Hi,Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jason answer could be solve your problem but I have this problem sometimes when using postman because I forgot to turn off the `SSL certificate verification`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You said the server is running at **https**://localhost:44366/ but you are sending requests to **http**://localhost:44366/

Comment: That's the first url I used. But when I run it it gives me an error of "Bad Request 400" {
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "Bad Request",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "|5e9a7fb9-4585aa9d52ce1629."
}

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,as @Json's answer,you need to send request by url:`https://localhost:44366/XXX`.

Then,For 400 Bad Request,you need to remove the following line:

```
[HttpPost]
//[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]   //remove this line
[Route("add-user")]
```